# Replace any words in URL

Tags: javascript, url, replace

I need to replace 2 words in my `window.location.href` when the user wants to follow it.

For example I'm a user and I want to go to this URL: `stackoverflow.com/questions/7821801/javascript-indexof` I need to replace `'7821801'` to `'js'` and `'-indexof'` to `'ok'` when page loads.

Or simply redirect user from `'mysite.com/css'` to `'mysite.com'`.

I tried

```
window.onload = function() {
    var urli = window.location.href;
    var arr = ['acasa', 'sktop'];

    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        if (urli.search(arr[i]) > 0) {
            document.getElementById('parv').innerHTML = urli.replace(arr[i], 'Tek');
        };
    };
}
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Do you want to replace the URL displayed to the user or do you want to instantly redirect the user to a modified URL?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect user, you should write
`window.location.href=document.getElementById('parv').innerHTML;`
after all manipulations

By the way, if you just want to redirect, there is no need in setting new url to some DOM element, just use another variable

Comment: Кать вот смотри, пользыватель хочет например на моем сайте заходить в подпапку к примеру mysite.com/content  а я  хочу что бы когда он этого захочет сделать то JS перенаправило его на главную а не в подпапку. может на английском прозвучало не так что ли (.

и там я указал масив со словами которые если будут присутствовать в ссылке, что бы перенаправило пользывателя на главную.